# How to add mailchimp to Node JS website (Vue)

Tags: html, vue.js, mailchimp, carbon-design-system

I got completely lost trying to implement Mailchimp on my Vue.js app. The objective is to build a simple email signup form.

Using Mailchimp, I am able to generate the following code:

```
<!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="https://pm.us1.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=xxxx" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address </label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_5119408c70596654ef4da6c1a_987baf3d10" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Resulting in: [image]
This works as intended however it lacks any style. I'm using the [Carbon Design System](https://www.carbondesignsystem.com/) that features styled components. However I am not sure how to add the functionality from the HTML code to the styled components.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <cv-form @submit.prevent="functie1">
      <cv-text-input
        label="Example text label"
        helper-text="Optional helper text here; if message is more than one line text should wrap (~100 character count maximum)"
        placeholder="Optional placeholder text"
      >
      </cv-text-input>
      <cv-button>Submit</cv-button>
    </cv-form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "SignupForm",
  methods: {
    functie1: function() {
      console.log("add email to userlist");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

resutling in [image]. What I don't get is whether I should use another library like Axios or requests to make the POST request to Mailchimp. Any help is welcome.

Comment: use axios (or any other lib inc built in fetch) to send the request to the url which you have in the form action, then handle the errors returned as it will be json, you dont need to implement the css classes `mc-field-group` etc

Comment: MailChimp does not support axios (CORS restriction), any other approaches? I am not sure how this should work. Can I communicate directly from the browser to MailChimp or do I need to use another (backend) server?